# Reinforcement Learning: Bellman Equations and relations for optimal (state)/value function?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning

This question is about (stationary) Markov Decision Processes in the case of discounted reward.

My questions are:

- Why is $v^*(s) = \sup_{a \in A} Q^*(s,a)$?
- Why is $Q^*(s,a) = E[R_t|S_t=s, A_t=a] + \gamma \int_{S} p(s'|s,a) v^*(s) ds'$?
- Given that we have an optimal policy $\pi^*$, why is $Q^* = Q^{\pi^*}$?

**NOTE:** I am seeking mathematical rigorous proofs, not 'intuitive explanations' :-)

**NOTE:** In case of equations nr. 1 and 2 I would prefer a proof that does not explicitly refer to an optimal policy.

Thanks in advance!!!

---

**More info on the setup:**

Given a set of states $S$, a set of actions $A$ and 'input' distributions

- $p(r|s',a,s)$ (the density value for a reward $r$ given that the agent just moved from state $s$ to state $s'$ using action $a$)
- $p(s'|a,s)$ (the density value for the underlying automata having chosen to actually move into step $s'$ given that the agent was in state $s$ and did choose action $a$)

and leaving the term $p(a|s)$ variable (the policy, i.e. the rules according to which the agent moves across the state space) we define the vector space $V$ of bounded functions $v : S \to \mathbb{R}$ and $W$ of bounded functions $w : S \times A \to \mathbb{R}$. Let us assume that the rewards are bounded so that every policy $\pi$ induces elements in $V$ and $W$ by putting

$$G_t := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \gamma^k R_{t+k}$$
(a random variable) and
  $$v^\pi(s) := E^\pi[G_t | S_t=s]$$
and
  $$Q^\pi(s,a) := E^\pi[G_t | S_t=s, A_t=a]$$
where we use the quirky notation $E^\pi$ to say that this (factorization of the conditional expectation) was computed in an MDP that was setup with policy $\pi$, i.e. $p(a|s) = \pi(a|s)$. Here, the expressions are actually independent of $t$, hence, we define these for $t$ arbitrary. We define

$$v^*(s) := \sup_\pi v^\pi(s)$$
and
  $$Q^*(s,a) := \sup_\pi Q^\pi(s,a)$$
Now in many books and references, people give different relations between $v^*$ and $Q^*$ usually without a proof. I have managed to reduce all of them to the ones mentioned above.

---

**Things I already know:**

Assuming that we have a discrete optimal policy $\pi$ and the third equation I am able to show the second equation: Let this policy be $\pi$ then $v^* = v^\pi$ and $v^\pi(s) = Q^\pi(s,\pi(s))$. Using the Bellman equation for $Q^\pi$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
  Q^*(s,a) &= Q^\pi(s,a) \\
  &= E[R_t|S_t=s,A_t=a] + \gamma \int_{s',a'} p(s',a'|s,a) Q^\pi(s',a') ds'da' \\
  &= E[R_t|S_t=s,A_t=a] + \gamma \int_{s'} p(s'|s,a) Q^\pi(s',\pi(s')) ds' \\
  &= E[R_t|S_t=s,A_t=a] + \gamma \int_{s'} p(s'|s,a) v^\pi(s') ds' \\
  &= E[R_t|S_t=s,A_t=a] + \gamma \int_{s'} p(s'|s,a) v^*(s') ds'
\end{align*}

(because $p(s',a'|s,a)$ should be zero except for the case when $a'=\pi(s')$ ... (?))

I am also able to prove '$\leq$' in eq. no. 1 (without any reference to an optimal policy!):
For every policy $\pi$,

### \begin{align*}
  v^\pi(s) &= \int_{a} p(a|s) E[G_t|S_t=s,A_t=a] da \\
    &= \int_{a} p(a|s) Q^\pi(s,a) da \\
    &\leq \int_{a} p(a|s) \left[\sup_{\tilde{a}} Q^\pi(s,\tilde{a})\right] da \\ 
    &= \sup_{\tilde{a}} Q^\pi(s,\tilde{a}) \cdot 1
\end{align*}

**I don't know whether that helps but I also know it ...**
As in the case of value functions in $V$, every policy $\pi$ induces an affine linear operator on $W$ by $L_\pi = r_\pi + \gamma P_\pi$ i.e.
  $$(r_\pi + \gamma P_\pi)(w)(s,a) = E[R_t|S_t=s,A_t=a] + \gamma \int_{s',a'} p(s',a'|s,a) w(s',a') ds'da'$$
$Q^\pi$ is the unique fixed point of $L_\pi$ and $Q^*$ is the unique fixed point of the operator
  $$\mathcal{L}(w)(s,a) := \sup_{\pi} (L_\pi w)(s,a)$$
(one proves these assertions just as in the case for $V$, see for example the book by Puterman)

Comment: 1. I'm pretty sure these are definitions, not subject to proof.  2. Since $v^*(s)$ is defined as the value of being in state $s$ given you take the best action when in that state, i.e., follow the optimal policy, it's a bit hard to make statements about it without at least implicitly referring to the policy, and similarly for $Q^*(\cdot)$.

Comment: @jbowman: 1. The only way I know to show that there is an optimal policy heavily involves the definition of $v^*$ being $\sup_\pi v^\pi$ (see Puterman, Markov Decsion Processes). So we must define $v^*$ as $\sup_\pi$. Hence, these are not subject to definitions but to proofs. Or phrased differently: If there are two natural but possible contradicting definitions... why do they coincide? 2. Well, it is possible at least for the first equation (partially)... so yes, I think that there is a policy free way to do that. Otherwise all of these statements would be subject to the assumption of..

Comment: an optimal policy and these assumptions are usually complicated and messy (either state space and action space are finite *or* state space is compact and reward function is upper semicontinuous *or* ... and so forth). That would be a pretty bad situation.

Comment: I think you are overthinking this :)  Those are definitions.  There is no contradiction between them.  $v^*(s)$ is the best reward (writing loosely) you can get in state $s$, and $Q^*(s,a)$ is the expected reward of taking action $a$ in state $s$ given that at all future epochs you will behave optimally.  The Bellman optimality principle is what tells you that splitting up an MDP this way actually gives you the optimal solution (leaving out a lot as this is a comment, btw) and under what conditions.

Comment: Hmm... There are two (ad hoc) different definitions of $v^*$: The first one is $v^*(s) = \sup_{\pi} v^\pi(s)$ (i.e. $v^*$ is the 'maximal' value function that is 'better' than every policy). The second one is $v^* = \sup_a Q^*(s,a)$. Although there might be reasons why those need to coincide it is absolutely not clear that they actually do. So: Why is $\sup_\pi v^\pi(s) = \sup_a \sup_\pi Q^\pi(s,a)$ (mathematically, not intuitively)? There are many examples of assertions that should be true/false but in fact, are not :-) That is why we need mathematical proofs for them.

Comment: Now I understand your question (I hope :) The Banach Fixed-Point theorem gets you there.  The final relationship in your comment is the fixed point.  Obviously showing why this is so is way too big for a comment!

Comment: No. The Banach fixed point helps you to see that $v^*$ and $Q^*$ actually are fixed points of the respective operators... you cannot expect it to show an equation as above because it involves one single function, not two different ones...

Comment: $Q^*$ is defined in terms of $v^*$ and vice versa.   Banach is what tells you that policy iteration works, and that's the constructive proof you want, I believe.

Comment: Are we still talking about the same thing here? $Q*$ is defined in terms of $Q^\pi$ and not in terms of $v^*$... policy iteration and all the algorithms tell you that you can optimize a policy to achieve $v^*$ as its value function. How does that help relating $v^*$ to $Q^*$???

Comment: Look at your second equation.  $Q^*(s,a)$ has a $v^*(s)$ on the rhs.  Therefore $Q^*$ *is* defined in terms of $v^*$.  $v^*$ is related to $Q^*$ by its definition, which is in your first line...  I think I'll refrain from further comments, because it seems we are talking past each other; I clearly don't understand what it is *you* don't understand, even though you do!  Maybe I'll be able to figure it out later and be able to write something helpful.